# Automatic incremental backups to an encrypted external hard disk

Tags: backup, encryption, external-hdd

What is the best way to do automatic incremental backups (and if possible to store more than a single version of the same file) to an external usb hard disk with full hard disk encryption?

I don't want to use the ubuntu backup utility (that provide an encryption feature) because I tested it and it seems really resources intensive and it is not really useful if I need to browse my backup searching for a specific file.

I'm thinking about rsync and cron on a external hard disk with a encryptfs partition but probably there is something better.

I also need to automate in some way the mount/umount process because I don't want to type the password every day to let the backup begin

Thank you! :-)

Comment: Did you read the [comparison of backup tools](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools) post?